# SAP .NET Connector BAPI_FUNCLOC_GETLIST RfcCommunicationException

Tags: sap-erp, bapi, sap-dotnet-connector

When I attempt to invoke the `IRfcFunction` `BAPI_FUNCLOC_GETLIST`, I get an `RfcCommunicationException` that says

> Syntax or generation error in a screen

I followed the instructions [here](http://www.dataxstream.com/2012/03/sap-nco-3-0-how-to-pass-table-parameters-to-sap-rfc/), but can't seem to get `BAPI_FUNCLOC_GETLIST` to process.

What is the problem with the code?

NB: I can process `BAPI_MATERIAL_GETLIST` like so and I get results.

Code to call `BAPI_FUNCLOC_GETLIST` (`RfcCommunicationException`):

```
    SAPSystemConnect cfg = new SAPSystemConnect();
    RfcDestinationManager.RegisterDestinationConfiguration(cfg);
    RfcDestination dest = RfcDestinationManager.GetDestination("mySAPdestination");
    RfcRepository repo = dest.Repository;
    IRfcFunction func = repo.CreateFunction("BAPI_FUNCLOC_GETLIST");

    IRfcTable tbl = func.GetTable("FUNCLOC_RA");

    tbl.Append();
    tbl.SetValue("SIGN", "I");
    tbl.SetValue("OPTION", "CP");
    tbl.SetValue("LOW", "MY-FL*");            

    func.SetValue("FUNCLOC_RA", tbl);
    IRfcTable tbl2 = func.GetTable("FUNCLOC_LIST");

    func.Invoke(dest); // I get an RfcCommunicationException here that says
                       // "Syntax or generation error in a screen."

    DataTable dt = tbl2.ToDataTable("table1");

    foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("{0}", row.Field<string>(0));
    }
```

Code to call `BAPI_MATERIAL_GETLIST` (works fine):

```
    SAPSystemConnect cfg = new SAPSystemConnect();
    RfcDestinationManager.RegisterDestinationConfiguration(cfg);
    RfcDestination dest = RfcDestinationManager.GetDestination("mySAPdestination");
    RfcRepository repo = dest.Repository;
    IRfcFunction func = repo.CreateFunction("BAPI_MATERIAL_GETLIST");

    IRfcTable tbl = func.GetTable("MATNRSELECTION");            
                    
    tbl.Append();
    tbl.SetValue("SIGN", "I");
    tbl.SetValue("OPTION", "BT");
    tbl.SetValue("MATNR_LOW", "10");
    tbl.SetValue("MATNR_HIGH", "20");

    func.SetValue("MATNRSELECTION", tbl);
    IRfcTable tbl2 = func.GetTable("MATNRLIST");

    func.Invoke(dest);
                   
    DataTable dt = tbl2.ToDataTable("table1");

    foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("{0}", row.Field<string>(0));
    }
```

Comment: Check the transaction `ST22` in the ABAP system - any short dumps there?

Comment: I have no authorization to ST22.

Comment: try contacting your admins. The short dump should give you an idea of what's going wrong. And you can get rid of the line "func.SetValue("FUNCLOC_RA", tbl);". The table is already part of the function module object, you don't need to set it again. Btw I tested the FM in one of our ECC 6.0 systems and your parameters seem valid, at least it didn't dump on me.

Comment: You Do not need to Set the table with setValue back to the function. Try it without

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is really old, but thought I'd share what I found. Some BAPIs seem to work regardless of how your config parameters are set. Here's an example:

```
public RfcConfigParameters GetParameters(string destinationName)
    {

        RfcConfigParameters parms = new RfcConfigParameters();

        if (destinationName.Equals("mySAPdestination"))
        {
            parms.Add(RfcConfigParameters.AppServerHost, "sapnode.mycompany.net");
            parms.Add(RfcConfigParameters.SystemNumber, "21");
            parms.Add(RfcConfigParameters.SystemID, "CF1");
            parms.Add(RfcConfigParameters.User, "mySAPuser");
            parms.Add(RfcConfigParameters.Password, "mySAPpassword");
            parms.Add(RfcConfigParameters.Client, "100");
            parms.Add(RfcConfigParameters.Language, "EN"); 
            parms.Add(RfcConfigParameters.PoolSize, "5");
        }
        return parms;

    }
```

What I found I needed to get any BAPI, that was available to me, to work, was to ensure I connected using the "RfcConfigParameters.LogonGroup" parameter...

```
parms.Add(RfcConfigParameters.LogonGroup, "GRPX")
```

Answer (score 1):

"Syntax or generation error in a screen."

It looks like BAPI_FUNCLOC_GETLIST (or some subroutine it is calling internally) has syntax errors. As this is a standard BAPI delivered by SAP, this is quite unusual... :-)

And when you try to call a function module with syntax errors, the SAP system dumps and aborts the connection. (Though I would expect an RfcSystemException in this case, not an RfcCommunicationException!?)

Can it be that the import of some patch or hotpackage into your SAP system has failed and damaged the ABAP code of that function module (or of internally used components) or left it in an inconsistent state?